# How to add error message to this php function?

Tags: php, sql-server

I've added `NOT IN` so it wont include `21` and `25` when displaying the `Knights` but I want to add message like clan not found and etc but it will says something else.

```
    if (!isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $this->Error('CLAN_NOT_FOUND');
        return;
    }

    $db = $this->database[GDB];
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);

    $num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT IDName FROM KNIGHTS WHERE IDNum = ? AND IDNUM NOT IN (21,25)', $id);
    if ($num_rows == -1)
    {
        $this->Error('DB_ERROR');
        $db->getError();
        return;
    }
    else if ($num_rows == 0)
    {
        $this->Error('CLAN_NOT_FOUND');
        return;
    }
```

I've already created `CLAN_CANNOT_DISPLAY` but I don't know how to include it correctly and securely on the function above. If someone is able to help me out and show me how it should look .. I'll be really grateful.

EDIT: `I use MSSQL Server 2005`

Kind Regards.

Comment: if `IDNum` is a param, why not check `!= 21,25` within PHP? Why make a round trip to the server?

Comment: So can you please show me how it should look including the error message `CLAN_CANNOT_DISPLAY` ?

Comment: BTW, you have a typo. You cannot put `IDNum = ? AND IDNUM`, it should be `IDNum = ? AND IDNum` or `IDNUM = ? AND IDNUM`, depending on your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the IDs you don't want from PHP, save yourself a round trip. For example...

Replace:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);

$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT IDName FROM KNIGHTS WHERE IDNum = ? AND IDNUM NOT IN (21,25)', $id);
```

With:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
if (in_array($id,array(21,25)))
{
    $this->Error('CLAN_CANNOT_DISPLAY');
    return;
}

$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT IDName FROM KNIGHTS WHERE IDNum = ?', $id);
```

Comment: I deleted my answer as I wrote it expecting you wouldn't expand further. You've got my +1.

Comment: Is this a secure one ? Thanks for the +1.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia: I almost wasn't going to so no worries--I'll consider this as you having my back.

Comment: Its really helpful but can you lastly let me know if thats secure one as you've provided it ?

Comment: @nRov: Not sure what you mean by secure. It's no more/less secure than what you have (just removes a round-trip if the IDs are one of the two exceptions).

Comment: It works. So, you say that its as I provided it just removing a round-trip and its secure as my previous one but even better removing the round-trip .. I can use it safely ? I will wait for you answer, so I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: @nRov: Al it does is if the ID is either 21 or 25 it errors out. Everything else executes as you have, so it's just as secure--just more optimized.

Comment: @nRov: Yes, it just was shorter than `if ($id == 21 || $id == 25){` (and allowed you to add other IDs easier at a later date, or make that list generated from something else).

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. I can accept it now. Feels secured. Hehehe